# Split window vertically and edit visually selected file

Tags: vim-windows, split

I like what the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> does, but I want to have a vertical split instead of horizontal.

I managed to achieve this by defining the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <c-w>f :vertical wincmd f<cr>
```

and in normal mode it works perfectly. But I failed to do the same for **visual mode**.

What I have tried so far:

```
" This yields 'E481: No range allowed
vnoremap <c-w>f :vertical wincmd f<cr>

" This just ignores my selection and behaves like <c-w>f in normal mode,
" i.e. attempts to open the file under cursor
vnoremap <c-w>f :<c-u>vertical wincmd f<cr>
```

How can I do such a thing for the visual mode?

Comment: `<C-W>f` is only defined for Normal mode. What makes you think it'll be of use in Visual mode too?

Comment: @Matt I tried it without any custom mappings and found out that it works in visual mode. E. g. if you have line `/home/ovandriyanov` and visually select only `/home`, then vim opens `/home`, while in normal mode it opens `/home/ovandriyanov`. The only thing I would like to change is to have vertical split instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you press `:` you got into cmdline-mode. And there's no direct way back into Visual from it (except `normal! gv` and such, but that's indirect through Normal). See `:h mode-switching`, because it's essential to understand how Vim works.

Therefore, you must do it in a different manner: while still in the Visual yank the selection and put it into the command line.

```
vnoremap <c-w>f y:vsplit +find<bslash><space><c-r>"<cr>
```

Note: if file name contains spaces you might also want to use `:h escape()` function.

BTW. The Normal mode mapping could also be rewritten in a similar manner:

```
nnoremap <c-w>f :vsplit +find<bslash><space><c-r><c-f><cr>
```

There's a single problem though: it always splits first, even if a file name was not found in path.

Comment: This is definetely a useful answer which will help me to figure out a proper solution, but I must say that the proposed solution indeed behaves imperfectly when the selected file does not exist: not only it splits the window when the file does not exist, it also starts editing the new file instead of giving the error message about searching for non-existent file. I believe I can work this around with some complex function, though.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov Not sure how you got such behaviour. There's E345 if file was not found.

Comment: well I did nothing special, here is the tty capture demonstrating the issue https://terminalizer.com/view/6253c52a2672

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov You forgot backslash

Comment: You are right. Thanks!

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov So if planning to deal with "file not found" situation, you can `catch` it and close a split window.